Expansion of sum raised to a real exponent
I have a question that bothered me some time ago. It was whether one could expand $(\sum_{i} a_i)^{\alpha}$ as a bunch of sums of products. My exact question is kind of strange to formulate, but hopefully the next few examples make it clearer.
$$(\sum_i a_i)^2 = \sum_{l}\sum_{k} a_la_k$$
$$(\sum_i a_i)^3 = \sum_{l}\sum_{k}\sum_{m} a_la_ka_m$$
$$(\sum_i a_i)^4 = \sum_{l}\sum_{k}\sum_{m}\sum_{n} a_la_ka_ma_n$$
So I am wondering if anything similar exists for other real exponents for a bounded sum, let's say.

The formulae you mention come from the fact that exponentiation using positive numbers can be interpreted as repeated multiplication. What do you propose an alternative for this for real exponents?

Exactly. I am wondering if such repeated multiplication can work for real exponents

There is probably not an expression in the way you're looking for, but it is possible to expand out binomial expressions to non-integer powers using the binomial series, so if $|x| > |y|$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ then you can write
$$(x + y)^\alpha = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty {\alpha \choose n} x^{\alpha - n} y^n$$
where ${\alpha \choose n} = \frac{\alpha(\alpha - 1)\ldots(\alpha - n + 1)}{n!}$ is the generalised binomial coefficient.
Then if $|a_1| < |a_2| < \ldots < |a_m|$, you can extend this as
$$\begin{eqnarray} (a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_m)^\alpha & = & \sum_{n_1 = 0}^\infty {\alpha \choose n_1} a_1^{n_1} (a_2 + a_3 + \ldots + a_m)^{\alpha - m_1} \\
& = & \sum_{n_1 = 0}^\infty {\alpha \choose n_1} a_1^{n_1} \sum_{n_2 = 0}^\infty {\alpha - n_1 \choose n_2} a_2^{n_2} (a_3 + \ldots + a_m)^{\alpha - n_1 - n_2} \\
& = & \sum_{n_1 = 0}^\infty \sum_{n_2 = 0}^\infty \ldots \sum_{n_m = 0}^\infty {\alpha \choose n_1} {\alpha - n_1 \choose n_2} \ldots {\alpha - n_1 - n_2 - \ldots - n_{m - 1} \choose n_m} a_1^{n_1} a_2^{n_2} \ldots a_m^{n_m}
\end{eqnarray}$$
